# How can i reference another sheet name value with a cell?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am getting all the sheet names of a spreadsheet via a function. Now I want to reference the value of all the sheets. I can reference the values manually entering the names of the sheet. But I want to reference the sheet name via a cell. As the sheet names may update or change. So I want to use the reference **='ly-lkoan'!$H$6** something like **='k6'!$H$6** so the cell k6 containing the sheet name will be referenced. How can I achieve this?
[image]

Comment: INDIRECT........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigBen already commented the answer but I'd like to show you how just in case you still don't know how to use it.

#### Formula:

```
=INDIRECT(K6&"!$H$6")
```

We append the name of the sheet using `&` to `!` and its range.

#### Output:

### [image: output1]

[image: output2]

#### Reference:

- [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!! Saved a lot of headbanging :3. I was not sure how to use the Indirect here!! :)

Comment: Hi @RashedMazumder, glad you were able to fix your issue. If we answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Sure, Was unaware of the accept button. Thanks for pointing out ^_^

Comment: You're welcome @RashedMazumder. Welcome to StackOverflow.